# How to show shell hint (text that appears when hovering a file in Explorer) for a file programmatically

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-shell

This is what I want to get:

[image]

I know it's possible to get because Total Commander shows exactly the same info, although in a differently styled window. Which makes me think that there must be a way of querying this text for any given file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`IQueryInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761359%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface is what you want. Briefly (psuedo-code only, sorry):

```
PCUITEMID_CHILD pidl = <PIDL of item in question>
IShellFolder* psf = <IShellFolder parent folder of item in question>

IQueryInfo* pqi;
if (SUCCEEDED(psf->GetUIObjectOf(hWnd, 1, &pidl, 0, &pqi)))
{
    LPWSTR lpszTip;
    if (SUCCEEDED(pqi->GetInfoTip(0, &lpszTip)) && lpszTip)
    {
        // do something with the tip, and then free it
        CoTaskMemFree(lpszTip); 
    }
}
```

Once you have the text you can, of course, display it any way you like.

Comment: What programming language is the code above for? (I know you said pseudocode). This will help me figure out how to implement it.

Comment: @KAE: It's C++ (or possibly C).